# Purge URL from multiple Varnish Servers in multi domain setup

Tags: multistore, varnish

I would like to purge a specific URL from a multi varnish Server enviroment.
The extra is that we have multiple Domains running over the same Varnish.

```
curl -X PURGE -H 'X-Magento-Tags-Pattern: .*' -H 'Host: https://www.domain.de' http://12.34.56.78/path/to/product.html
```

The varnish server is configured like this in "sub vcl_hash"

```
# For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
if (req.http.host) {
    hash_data(req.http.host);
} else {
    hash_data(server.ip);
}
```

i am watching varnish like `varnishlog -g request -q 'ReqMethod eq "PURGE"'`

```
*   << Request  >> 3096028
-   Begin          req 3096027 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1692698848.940666 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1692698848.940666 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        reload_20230821_145932_15180
-   ReqStart       11.22.33.44 54242 a0
-   ReqMethod      PURGE
-   ReqURL         /path/to/product.html
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Accept: */*
-   ReqHeader      Host: https://www.domain.de
-   ReqHeader      X-Magento-Tags-Pattern: .*
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 11.22.33.44
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   VCL_acl        MATCH purge "11.22.33.44"
-   VCL_return     synth
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   Timestamp      Process: 1692698848.940763 0.000097 0.000097
-   RespHeader     Date: Tue, 22 Aug 2023 10:07:28 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 3096028
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     200
-   RespReason     OK
-   RespReason     Purged
-   VCL_call       SYNTH
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 242
-   Storage        malloc Transient
-   Filters
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1692698848.940817 0.000151 0.000054
-   ReqAcct        114 0 114 220 242 462
-   End
```

All looks fine, but as the result of the PURGE Request, that every site of the same domain and also any other domains are purged, like i someone has cleaned the full cache

Does anybody see what i am missing?

Update: VCL Configuration:

```
# VCL version 5.0 is not supported so it should be 4.0 even though actually used Varnish version is 6
vcl 4.0;

import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 6.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https'

backend default {
    .host = "12.34.56.78";
    .port = "7080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
}

acl purge {
    "11.22.33.44";
}

sub vcl_recv {

    if (req.restarts > 0) {
        set req.hash_always_miss = true;
    }
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
        # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
        # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass shopping cart, checkout and search requests
    if (req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "/pub/health_check.php") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unknown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove all marketing get parameters to minimize the cache objects
    if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|__hs[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+|_)=") {
    set req.http.X-Original-Url = req.url;
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+|__hs[a-z]+|_)=[-_A-z0-9+()%.]+&?", "");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "[?|&]+$", "");
    }

    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
        return (pass);

        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
        #unset req.http.Https;
        #unset req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto;
        #unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    # For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    }
    

    if (req.url ~ "/graphql") {
        call process_graphql_headers;
    }
}

sub process_graphql_headers {
    if (req.http.Store) {
        hash_data(req.http.Store);
    }
    if (req.http.Content-Currency) {
        hash_data(req.http.Content-Currency);
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 3d;
                                        

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s
    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }else {
        set beresp.ttl = 604800s;
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
             set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
    } else {
             set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
            set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }

    # Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
#    if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
#        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
#        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
#        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
#    }

    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (restart);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please the complete VCL file to the question. There is probably a lot more logic related to cache invalidation that is currently missing. Once that information is shared in the question, I can provide a more educated explanation.

Comment: @ThijsFeryn i added the configuration of Varnish

Answer (score 0):

### The current situation

Based on your VCL, the `PURGE` request method is used to remove objects from the cache using the `X-Magento-Tags-Pattern` request header or `X-Pool` request header.

The headers are leveraged in the `ban()` function to add these patterns to the ban list. The ban lurker thread is responsible for removing objects from the cache that match these ban expressions.

See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/ban/ for a tutorial about banning.

Here's the if statement that is used for that:

```
if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
    ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
}
if (req.http.X-Pool) {
    ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
}
```

As you can see there is no context that refers to any specific host. A matched object will apply to every domain you have.

### Host-based banning

If you want to be host-specific, a slight VCL modification will add host context to the bans.

First you need to add the `Host` header value to the object as a header. This adds request information to the response, which will be stored in the object. At the same time it strips the header off again at delivery time:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.http.X-Host = bereq.http.Host;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    unset resp.http.X-Host;
}
```

You can then match that value in your `ban()` function. The if-statement we referred to earlier, now looks like this:

```
if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
    ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern + " && obj.http.X-Host == " + req.http.Host);
}
if (req.http.X-Pool) {
    ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool + " && obj.http.X-Host == " + req.http.Host);
}
```

You can trigger the bans using the same `curl` call:

```
curl -X PURGE -H 'X-Magento-Tags-Pattern: .*' -H 'Host: www.domain.de' http://12.34.56.78/path/to/product.html
```

> But keep in mind that the `Host` header is an FQDN and not a URL. Please don't include `http://`. Please also keep in mind that the URL itself doesn't matter. You can do the purge on any URL you want, it will have the same impact.

### Use purges for individual invalidations

If you're interested in removing individual objects from the cache based on the URL (like the hypothetical `http://12.34.56.78/path/to/product.html` example, you can also use traditional purges in Varnish.

This is a different mechanism than bans, but is not mutually exclusive in your VCL configuration.

The only difference would be removing the following if-statement from your VCL:

```
if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
    return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
}
```

And replacing it with the following if-statement:

```
if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
    return (purge);
}
```

This would allow you to run the following `curl` call:

```
curl -X PURGE -H 'Host: www.domain.de' http://12.34.56.78/path/to/product.html
```

And would result in `www.domain.de/path/to/product.html` being removed from the cache. Because we didn't specify `X-Magento-Tags-Pattern` or `X-Pool`, the URL and `Host` header are used for invalidation. If you do specify any of these headers, banning based on tags is used.

See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/purge/ for a purging tutorial.